# Is there a way to copy the selected text within a text box with VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, object, text, copy

I have replaced the ctrl+c shortcut with a macro that performs additional instructions when copying a range.

When the selection is not a range, the program should simply copy the current selection. It seemed to work perfecly fine until I tried to copy some text from within a TextBox (and basically any text that is within an object). When pasting, it just pastes the object and not the selected text within the object.

Here's my code :

> 

```
Sub ShadowCopy()

Dim Rg As Range, Source As Range
Dim Ad As String, Nm As String, flag As Integer, i As Integer, obj As Integer
Dim Hs As Integer, Ls As Integer, y As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

obj = 0
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
    Selection.Copy
    obj = 1
    
Else
    If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
        Set Source = Application.Selection
            Nm = Source.Worksheet.name
            Hs = Application.Min(Source.Rows.Count, 1000)
            Ls = Application.Min(Source.Columns.Count, 1000)
            Ad = Source.Address
        
        flag = 0
        For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).name = "ShadowCopy" Then
                Sheets("ShadowCopy").Columns(1).Clear
                Sheets("ShadowCopy").Columns(3).Clear
                flag = 1
            End If
        Next i
        
        If flag = 0 Then
            Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = "ShadowCopy"
            Source.Worksheet.Activate
        End If
            
        Worksheets("ShadowCopy").Visible = False
        Sheets("ShadowCopy").Cells(1, 1) = Nm
        Sheets("ShadowCopy").Cells(2, 1) = Ad
        Sheets("ShadowCopy").Cells(3, 1) = Hs
        Sheets("ShadowCopy").Cells(4, 1) = Ls
        
        For y = 1 To Hs
            Sheets("ShadowCopy").Cells(y, 3) = Source.Rows(y).RowHeight
        Next y
    End If
End If


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If obj = 0 Then
Source.Copy
End If

End Sub
```

The part that does not work as intended is:

```
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
    Selection.Copy
    obj = 1
```

It is as if the selection does not change when I select the text in the TextBox. However, when I recorded the text selection, the corresponding code implies that my selection should have changed when I selected the text in the TextBox:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox Source")).Select
```

Is there a way to copy the text highlighted by the cursor in a TextBox/Object ?

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: What kind of text box are you talking about? A sheet `ActiveX` or `Form` type

Comment: Do you like selecting/copying all text box text, or only **part of it**?

Comment: I'm guessing its `Form` type object (inserted via the Insert tab of the ribbon).
In the course of my work I often use textBox/Objects to add comments to my sheets. The objective is to be able to copy part of the text of the TextBox to paste it elsewhere but not all of the text.

Comment: I guess OP don't want to *select* anything. The user selects text within the text of the shape and presses Ctrl+C. OP overwrites the regular shortcut with a macro. Within this macro, some magic is done (displaying a message or whatever) and the marked text should be copied. However, `selection` returns the selected shape, not the marked text within that shape. I would guess that this information is not exposed to VBA.

Comment: @FunThomas Yes this is what I intend to do.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the whole text content of the box via `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange` however I have no idea how to get the position of the cursor within the box in order to only keep the part of the text I want to copy.

Comment: As I said, I don't think that this information is exposed to VBA. And even if: Would you copy also the font (color, Size...)? This could be an endless list of things that you have to implement. As a user, I would be surprised (and angry) if standard functionality no longer works.

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot know (in the way you show) that selected text box/shape is `Shapes(1)`. I can show you how to extract the text box object from selection, but it exposes only its whole text, **not selected one**...

Comment: @FunThomas That would be unfortunate... You think it's impossible even if I try to dabble with the GetCursorPos function ? Or is there an equivalent of the .SelStart property on Excel ?
I am only interested in the text as the objects I use all have a similar font size/color format.

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes my bad I need to replace `1` with the current selected object

Comment: A piece of code can detect which part of the text has the font colored in red, but not if that part is selected... The issue of selected text box identification can be solved, but not the one related to partial text selection. If it's not too much for the users (I think it is...) if they will make some characters of a specific color, that part of the selected text box can be identified. But it is more difficult then using `Ctrl +C`... In fact, can you explain why do you use this way of selection identification/copying?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am designing an Add-in on excel that will used by my co-workers. Some of the functionalities I implement allow new pasting options such as paste row heights (like paste columns width) or to paste formulas without changing cell references (even if there is no $). To do so I need to store some informations about the source range (Address, Row count, Column Count, Heights of the rows in the source). I have not been able to find a way of getting these information other than by having them stored in an hidden sheet. I do not think i can get these informations from the clipboard...

Comment: As the Add-in will be used by co-workers, I want it to be as "ergonomic" as possible hence the ctrl+c override. If it was just for my personal use I would simply bind the macro to another shortcut and call it a day :)